# Navigate to error jsp when filter blocks access to a jsp

Tags: java, jsp, filter, error-handling, web.xml

in my Java application I've added the following filter and filter-mapping to the web.xml file.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allow</param-name>
        <param-value>127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This only allows access to calls from the localhost engine. This works because when I try to run from another location, I receive the following in my browser: **HTTP 403 - Forbidden**

But I want to redirect in that case to my error-page, which I also defined  like the following way:

```
<error-page>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

How to realize this?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to specify `<error-code>`

```
<error-page>
     <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: I added it, but it didn't change anything.